# How do I create bulk upserts for azure tables with Azure.Data.Tables

Tags: c#, azure

I am currently dipping my toes in the water with azure table storage.

I am using `Azure.Data.Tables` rather than `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table`, since I could read that it was the newer version, which would be maintained.

So now I have this class, which has to methods, one for upserting, and one for upserting many entities:

```
public class TableRepository
{



    private TableServiceClient _tableServiceClient;
    private TableClient _tableClient;

    public TableRepository(string key, string table)
    {
        _tableServiceClient = new TableServiceClient(key);
        _tableClient = _tableServiceClient.GetTableClient(tableName: table);
    }

    public async Task AddAsync(TableEntity mapping)
    {

        await _tableClient.UpsertEntityAsync(mapping);
    }
    public async Task AddEntitiesToTableAsync(IEnumerable<TableEntity> mappings)
    {
        foreach (var m in mappings)
        {
            await _tableClient.UpsertEntityAsync(m);
        }
    }
}
```

And for my bulk upsert, this works, but is slow for many upserts, I wanted to see If I could upsert entities in bulk.

I figured out that for `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table`, I could execute a batch of operations, and do something like this:

```
public async Task AddEntitiesToTableAsync(IEnumerable<EmailToIdMapping> mappings)
{
    // Retrieve the CloudTable instance representing your Azure Storage table
    CloudTable table = GetCloudTable(); // Replace with your own logic to get the CloudTable

    // Create a List of TableOperation to hold the batch operations
    List<TableOperation> batchOperations = new List<TableOperation>();

    foreach (var m in mappings)
    {
        var tableEntity = new DynamicTableEntity(m.PartitionKey, m.RowKey)
        {
            Properties = new Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>
            {
                { "Email", new EntityProperty(m.Email) },
                { "Id", new EntityProperty(m.Id) }
            }
        };

        // Create an InsertOrReplace operation for the entity
        TableOperation upsertOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(tableEntity);
        batchOperations.Add(upsertOperation);
    }

    // Create a TableBatchOperation with the batch operations
    TableBatchOperation batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();
    batchOperation.AddRange(batchOperations);

    // Execute the batch operation
    await table.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchOperation);
}
```

But I cannot find anything similar for `Azure.Data.Tables`, the only thing I can think of is to find a smarter way to do the thing I am already doing more effeciently in parralel

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Try out the `SubmitTransactionAsync` method in `Azure.Data.Tables`

```
try
{
    var actions = new List<TableTransactionAction>();

    // Iterate over the entities and add up values
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        var upsertAction = new UpsertEntityAction(entity);
        actions.Add(upsertAction);
    }

    var transaction = new TableTransaction(actions);
    var tableClient = client.GetTableClient("<pass-your-table-name-here>");

    // Execute as a batch transaction
    await tableClient.SubmitTransactionAsync(transaction);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw;
}
```

Note that in order to you to succeed you should have the same partitioning key. Otherwise, as of my knowledge, there is no you can achieve batch transactions

Comment: Thank you. I might be bad at this,  but I have Azure.Data.Tables 12.8.0 imported, but it can't find UpsertEntityAction or TableTransaction

Comment: Can you try uninstalling and reinstalling the package

Comment: Yes, this had no effect

Comment: Can you check this link - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables/samples/Sample6TransactionalBatch.md  where it has this mentioned